# Memory leakage in C - dynamic array losing data

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have a `function1` where I allocate an array with a specific number of bytes each time.

When I use `printf` I can see that my data is loaded on this array.

```
function1 (other arguments, CvPoint2D32f* array1)
```

Then there is a `function2` in which I call `function1` and assign the array1 data to another variable (array2).

```
function2(other stuff, CvPoint2D32f* array2)
```

When I use `printf` I can see that I cannot access my data. The program prints 0.000..

`function2` is called by my main program in which I assign the data to a third variable...

I search and I search but cannot find what is wrong.

Passing the pointer is not enough already?

Help, if I was not specific enough, ask me:

```
function1(IplImage* grey, IplImage* image, CvPoint2D32f *array1){

    int array_counter = cvFindContours(grey, storage_color, &colorcontoursizeof(CvContour),
                                 CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
    array1 = (CvPoint2D32f*)malloc(array_counter*sizeof(CvPoint2D32f))
    if (array_counter == 0){
        printf("Error allocating memory or Just a colour missing!!!\n\n\n");
        free(Man);
    }

    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage_color); // Releasing memory.
    free(Man);

    return array_counter;
}    


int function2(IplImage* image, CvPoint2D32f *array2, other stuff){

    ...other stuff...      

     // Find the contours for the different colors.
    r_counter = function1(image1, image2, array2);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT =======================================

I tried to do it before posting here but here is a problem I get.

I get an error when compiling at the line where I load data in the array1 about non-class type of CvPoint2D32f.

That is what I do at these lines where I get the error:

```
array1[cnt].x = (tpt1.x + tpt2.x)/2; 
array1[cnt].y = (tpt1.y + tpt2.y)/2;
```

2nd EDIT =========================

both answers helped and were correct. Thanks to everybody! The problem is solved.
I used double pointers to both the functions to export data from function1 to function2 and from function2 to main program. I used some temporary variables which helped a lot. It was less confusing.

Comment: If in your search you are using keywords similar to those used in your question then you probably will never find an answer... At least post a code or something...

Comment: For future questions, please have a look at [how to markup your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Trying to explain C pointer passing semantics, bear with me a little).

C only has pass-by-value, which means that you cannot alter an argument to a function. So in:

```
function1(IplImage* grey, IplImage* image, CvPoint2D32f *array1){
    ....
    array1 = (CvPoint2D32f*)malloc(array_counter*sizeof(CvPoint2D32f))
    ....
}
r_counter = function1(image1, image2, array2);
```

The change you made to `array1` in `function1` is not visible outside of that function (`array1` is passed by value, not by reference).

To get around this, pass to the function a variable that *contains a pointer* to the variable you want to pass by reference:

```
function1(IplImage* grey, IplImage* image, CvPoint2D32f **array1){
    ....
    *array1 = (CvPoint2D32f*)malloc(array_counter*sizeof(CvPoint2D32f))
    ....
}
r_counter = function1(image1, image2, &array2);
```

i.e. just add another level of indirection. See RFC 1925 truth 6a (*It is always possible to add another level of indirection.*).

Answer (score 2):

Two scenarios:

```
  // SCENARIO 1: Array allocated outside a function and passed into it
  myfunc (char * buff)
  {
     buff[0] = 'A';
     ...

  main ()
    ...
    char *mybuffer = NULL;
    if ((mybuffer = malloc (100))
      myfunc (mybuffer);
      ...
```

.

```
  // SCENARIO 2: Array allocated inside of a function and passed out from it
  myfunc (char **buff)
  {
     *buff = malloc (100);
     ...

  main ()
    char *mybuffer = NULL;
    myfunc (&mybuffer);
    ...
```

I think the problem is you probably need Scenario 2. Try "**pointer-to-pointer" syntax in your "function1()"

Comment: ok i will try and let you know.
thanks for your answers everybody

excuse me if question wasnt asked properly formatted